# Фраза "в размере..."

Tags: склонение

Здравствуйте!

Очень важно понять, какая фраза верная:

"в размере десяти тысяч рублей"
или
"в размере десять тысяч рублей".

Очень жду, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:  размере десяти тысяч рублей.

Из толкового словаря: РАЗМЕР,  2. Величина денежной суммы.  Начислить стипендию в размере **ста рублей.**

Answer (score 2):

В литературном тексте правильно управление по типу ***"в размере десяти тысяч рублей"***.

Но такая норма отступает под действием ряда факторов (попросту говоря, возникает вопрос *"А какой это размер у десяти тысяч?"*).

Такие слова как  "количество", "размер", "объем" и проч. в сочетании с группой числительного, при перечислении особенно, начинают "управлять" уже не дополнением, а несогласованным приложением в именительном падеже.  Поэтому, полагаю, в устной речи в целях лучшего восприятия несогласованный вариант ("в размере десять тысяч") возможен. Но в письменном тексте его лучше пока не использовать.